# How do I use cookies to let visitors access to the downloads page of my website

Tags: php, html, cookies

I want visitors to my website to fill out a contact form before they can access the downloads page. I am looking for online resources or examples. The only ones I can find are username and password authentication which I don't need. I am hoping to do it in PHP. At the moment my Contact form emails me their details but anyone can access the downloads page.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any code to show? -1 for lack of effort as it appears right now.

Comment: It's good to want things. We want to see an effort and code. So...not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving us much to go on!

Based on your tags I assume your developing in php. This tutorial should give you what you need [Website Authentication - a simple PHP sample](http://grover.open2space.com/node/109)

Comment: My sincere apologies, I am looking for online resources or examples. The only ones I can find are username and password authentication. I am hoping to do it in PHP. At the moment my Contact form emails me their details but anyone can access the downloads page.

Comment: Well the principals are all the same. You need to create a session when the user submits the form, and then check the session state on the downloads page. Information on php session variables here http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_2.htm